# Knockout foreach generate html fields

Tags: html, knockout.js

I want to display as many fields as user wants.

Maybe you have idea how can I do this case using foreach loop in Knockout framework.

For example `numberOfFields` is input field where user can enter how many fields he wants to display

```
<input id="numberOfFields" type="text" data-bind="value: obj().numberOfFields() />
<div data-bind="foreach: new Array(obj().numberofCashFlows())">
   <label for="quantity$index()">Flow number $index()</label>
   <input id="quantity$index()" type="text" data-bind="value: quantityArray[$index()]" />
</div>
```

Of course code doesn't work, I want to tell you what I mean.

If user enters 3 I want to show 3 labels and inputs with id `quantity1`, `quantity2`, `quantity3` and with values: `quantityArray[0]`, `quantityArray[1]`, `quantityArray[2]`

Can you help me or give some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, this should be it by approx. I've also added and observable to the Quantity to show you how you could expand on the example with bound properties.

```js
console.clear();

function Quantity(id, label) {
 var self = this;
  self.id = id;
  self.label = ko.observable(label);
};

ko.applyBindings(() => {
 var self = this;
  self.amount = ko.observable(0);
  self.quantity = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  self.amount.subscribe(function(amount) {
   var quantity = self.quantity().length;
    amount = Number(amount);
    if (amount > quantity) {
      for (var i = quantity; i < amount; i++) {
       self.quantity.push(new Quantity(i+1, 'label for ' + (i+1)));
      }
    } else if (amount < quantity) {     
     var minus = quantity - amount;
      for (var i = 0; i < minus; i++) {
       self.quantity.pop();
      }
    }
  });
  
  self.amount(2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<label>amount: </label>
<input type="number" data-bind="textInput: amount" min="0" />
<div data-bind="foreach: quantity">
    <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: label, attr: { placeholder: 'label for ' + id }" /><span data-bind="text: label"></span><br />
</div>
```